# Multiple colored <a> tags in TextView

Tags: android

Do you know how can I have multiple colored anchor tags in a `TextView`? I've tried using `Html.fromHTML("<a href='#'><font color='#f00'>text</font></a>")` but it doesn't work and I really need a html solution without using a webview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using double quotes:

```
<a href="#"><font color="#f00">text</font></a>
```

Beyond that, you will need to manually manipulate [the `ForegroundColorSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html) yourself.

Comment: It has a wierd behaivor : if I set it like Html.fromHTML("<a href="#"><font color="#f00">text</font></a>") then when I reverse it with Html.toHTML() it returns <font color="#f00"><a href="#">text</a></font> and of course it doesn't color the link. If I set the ForegroundColorSpan then it colours it and it returns the correct html when calling toHtml(). So it's no escaping your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Do you try `<font color="#f00"><a href="#">text</a></font>` ?

Comment: It doesn't color the text. Opened in a normal browser the correct html to insert is <a href='#'><font color='#f00'>text</font></a>.

Comment: Than what about #ff0000 instead of #f00